# Request for font file does not contain cookie used on referer CSS file (which has cookie)

Tags: html, css, iframe, cookies, fonts

I am writing a JavaScript EPub reader that accesses files using a content server and a cookie.  The reader uses an `<iframe>` to display the book contents (which is xhtml/js/css etc).  Setting the cookie using `document.cookie` and applying all the required cross-domain configurations (both client and server side) to my AJAX requests is working.  Files are being properly retrieved from the server when opening the book.

Except for the font files.

These font files are local to the book and not pulled from an outside URL.  The are located in the same location on the content server as the rest of the book.  However, the cookie is not being sent with the request as it is with other files.  The difference (at least, the only one I can see) is that this file is not being requested directly (as with a `<link>` or `<script>` tag), but as part of the loading of a CSS file.

I have attached some network request screenshots to hopefully show the issue in proper context.

First is the initial request to get the page file (XHTML).  It works and the cookie is shown in the request.  It works as intended.

Next is the request for a CSS file included within the XHTML page.  This request is also successful as it contains the cookie.  It does not have a referer value.  I'm not sure this matters, but it's the biggest difference.

[CSS File Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cd0U.png)

Lastly, the request for the font file that the CSS file needs.  This request fails because the cookie is not provided.  The request does have a referer value that is set to the CSS file

[Font File Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NUJF.png)

Only the initial request for the page file is done in the JavaScript (using XHR).  All other requests (everything contained on the XHTML page) are done by the `<iframe>`.  I would think it's something with the iframe, but considering other files are successfully loaded using the cookie (scripts, css, images, etc), it can't be that.  Maybe font files aren't supported this way?  I really don't know much about the nuance of iframes and how content is loaded in-browser.

Any help would be appreciated.